# Why this function is not invoked when calling jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, function, plugins

I have a function like this:

```
function typeahead_fn(combo){

  $(combo).typeahead({
      highlight:true,
      hint: false,
      minLength: 0,
      autoselect: false
  },
  {
      name: "bh",
      source: wrapper,
      displayKey: 'itemName',
      templates: {
        // empty: [
        //     '<div class="empty-message">',
        //     'no results found',
        //     '</div>'
        //   ].join('\n'),
          suggestion: function(data){
            return '<div class="comboRow"> <div class="comboColumn comboColumnEmpty"></div><div class="comboColumn comboColumnItemCode">' + data.itemCode + '</div> <div class="comboColumn comboColumnEmpty"></div> <div class="comboColumn comboColumnItemName">' + data.itemName + '</div> </div>';
          }
      },
      limit: 1000
  });
}
```

If I call it like this then it works fine:

```
  typeahead_fn('.itemCombo');
```

If I pass its reference to plugin it does not work:

```
  $("#tbl").editable({typeahead: typeahead_fn('.newItemCombo')});
```

**Update:**

If I do it in another way like this then it works:

```
  $("#tbl").editable({typeahead: function typeahead_fn(){

        $('.newItemCombo').typeahead({
            highlight:true,
            hint: false,
            minLength: 0,
            autoselect: false
        },
        {
            name: "bh",
            source: wrapper,
            displayKey: 'itemName',
            templates: {
              // empty: [
              //     '<div class="empty-message">',
              //     'no results found',
              //     '</div>'
              //   ].join('\n'),
                suggestion: function(data){
                  return '<div class="comboRow"> <div class="comboColumn comboColumnEmpty"></div><div class="comboColumn comboColumnItemCode">' + data.itemCode + '</div> <div class="comboColumn comboColumnEmpty"></div> <div class="comboColumn comboColumnItemName">' + data.itemName + '</div> </div>';
                }
            },
            limit: 1000
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass by "reference", you should remove the parenthesis and argument after the function name like:

```
$("#tbl").editable({typeahead: typeahead_fn});
```

If you want to pass the argument too, you should use and wrap your call in an anonymous function which will be passed by "reference":

```
$("#tbl").editable({typeahead: function () { typeahead_fn('.newItemCombo'); }});
```

Comment: No you completely misunderstood me. Here typeahead is an option in my plugin

Comment: Ho, then you should add this information in the question and share the code of your plugin relative to what you're doing with this option.

Comment: I think there is no mistake in Plugin. The way I am passing Parameter to the Plugin is wrong. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Well, the new example in the updated answer is not the same as the first one, the second one does not take any argument. We don't know what you're doing in your plugin with the `typeahead` option. If you use it like `option.typeahead()` for example, the first function can't work since it expect a parameter but that's pure speculation without the relevant code.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more relevant with all the new informations added in the comments & to the updated question.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. Thanks for the answer.